# Showing ng-messages with md-autocomplete without a floating label configured

Tags: angularjs, angular-material

I am using `md-autocomplete` and need to display a non floating label above the input whilst still being able to display validation messages as per other inputs inside a regular `md-input-container`.

For other inputs, I use `md-input-containers` with `label`s like so:

```
<md-input-container flex-gt-sm="50" md-no-float>
  <label translate>Pick Something</label>
  <input/>
</md-input-container>
```

I am trying something similar for an md-autocomplete, but when using this approach and not configuring an md-floating-label attribute, any validation messages that should appear fail to do so.

This codepen demonstrates this further - https://codepen.io/anon/pen/eWpVbd

You will see when clicking into the input and clicking away, the required ng-message appears. But if you then remove the `md-floating-label` attribute from the `md-autocomplete` so your are left with the non floating label 'Pick Something' you will no longer get validation messages.

Has anyone got any ideas how this can be achieved?

Comment: Thanks . I was facing serious problem with this from last few hours . This question helped me get my error messages . I used float labels and it worked .